# Relationship not set to null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, null, entity-framework-6.1

I have a very simple EF operation that fails: break the relationship between two entities as shown in the code below:

```
public async Task RemoveCurrentTeacherOfGroup(int groupId)
{
    var group = await _dataContext.Groups.SingleAsync(g => g.Id == groupId);
    group.Teacher = null;
    await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The database was generated code-first. The entities are defined like this:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ..
    public virtual List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ..
    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

However, breaking the relationship doesn't work, Teacher keeps pointing to the same entity. When stepping with the debugger, I see that the Teacher property doesn't become null after .Teacher = null. I tried it with the synchronous alternative, which had the same effect:

```
public void RemoveCurrentTeacherOfGroup(int groupId)
{
    var group = _dataContext.Groups.Single(g => g.Id == groupId);
    group.Teacher = null;
    _dataContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `Teacher` is not loaded you can't break the relationship. Either include it (eager-load) on the query:

```
_dataContext.Groups.Include(g => g.Teacher).Single(g => g.Id == groupId);
```

Or if lazy loading is enabled, access the property for reading before setting it to null:

```
var teacher = group.Teacher;
group.Teacher = null;
```

You see that "`Teacher` is not null after setting it to `null`" because the debugger is accessing the property for reading (lazy-loading it) after you have set it to `null`.

The value was already `null` before you hit the `group.Teacher = null` line since you hadn't previously loaded it (you can't however debug this, since accessing the property for reading would cause EF to actually load it if lazy loading is enabled). If you see the property value with the debugger **before** setting it to null, it'll work as expected and break the relationship, since `Teacher` would be loaded

Comment: Thank you! Off topic: I think this is a shortcoming in EF. The proxy object could detect setting to null in its setter; the foreign key is known (it is used for lazy loading), so EF could remove it and set the the property to modified state.

Comment: @mnwsmit I guess it's for performance reasons: if you are going to just "set the related entity" there's no need to roundtrip to the database to see if "it was null because it wasn't loaded, or it was null because it was actually null". Everything that roundtrips to the database must be carefully done (and setting the related entity does not *necessarily* need it)

Comment: However, that information is already known: inside the proxy object the foreign key is stored. So EF already knows the relation is only null because of lazy-loading.

Comment: Yes, but that's only a very specific case, there are far too many possible scenarios in EF (6, at least) for that check to be consistent and performant (ever tried to figure out relationship state changes from the Metadata in EF6? :-) ). I guess EF7 will be more to-the-point and things like these could be implemented (since they are removing all the bloat that noone uses :-) )

Comment: This means you have both the `Group` and the `Teacher` loaded in the context. Which is fine, but another way to do it is to use a foreign key, then you only have to have the `Group` loaded http://stackoverflow.com/a/28107793/150342

Comment: @Colin I agree, and I do it that way out of necessity (also for "relationship change tracking"), but in my head, this breaks the whole concept of ORM, by having to use "database-things" (a foreign key doesn't really make sense in an object->object relationship) in POCO classes. It's a tradeoff that you have to put up with for many things, but I hate that you have to.

Comment: That's why I linked to Julie Lerman's article on making do with absent foreign keys in that other question. Here's a direct link to Julie's article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708747.aspx

Comment: @Colin yes... that does not work for other scenarios though (for example, it won't help you track changes automatically unless you get into the scary deep inners of ObjectContext ... which will also be deprecated on EF7), and also requires "direct" access to the dbcontext for the logic, or would make it way more complicated for a layered app where the model classes are not connected to the dbcontext directly. It is doable, but requires a lot of mangling: if I have to choose one of the two bad situations, I'd rather just add the foreign key, but definitely YMMV. I just don't like either :-)

Comment: RIP 2hours of my life. Thank you!